# GUI architecture: Separation of Layout, Rendering, and Input

Tags: user-interface, architecture

All the GUI systems I've worked with involve a normalized base widget object that handles layout, input, and rendering. As I've been creating a game GUI in C++ I've been finding that specializing the roles of each widget so that each widget only handles layout, input, or rendering makes the code more composable, flexible, and organized.

However, as I've stretched that paradigm further and further it is starting to snap, and I am trying to find the sweet spot between normalized and specialized widgets.  My main difficulty is I have been unable to find any precedent for this GUI model.

- Is there a term for the concept I'm describing?
- Are there any existing systems or articles that contain this form of widget specialization?

[Edit]

Here is a code example for the traditional GUI model:

```
var button = new Widget()
button.width = 100
button.height = 30
button.set_fill(FILL_COLOR)
button.set_border(BORDER_COLOR, BORDER_SIZE)
button.click(()=> submit())
button.text = "Submit"
```

Here is a code example for the specialized GUI model:

```
var button = new Box()
button.width = 100
button.height = 30
button.add(new Fill(FILL_COLOR))
button.add(new Border(BORDER_COLOR, BORDER_SIZE))
button.add(new Clickable(()=> respond_to_click())
button.add(new Text("Submit"))
```

The first model relies on a large base class that contains many common GUI features, while the second breaks those features into minimal classes.  For the specialized approach, the Box class is only concerned about layout, while classes such as Fill and Clickable have no layout logic beyond inheriting the bounds of their parent.

Comment: Could you give concrete samples of code or at least UML diagrams that describes both approaches so that we can properly grasp your concept and the more traditionnal approach you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some ways you could view this as a [component-based architecture](https://www.raywenderlich.com/24878/introduction-to-component-based-architecture-in-games), which tends to be more popular in video games. The idea here is that separate "components" take different jobs, and usually get attached to something like a root "GameObject". In that sense, "button" might not even properly exist, but rather "control" - but with virtually no top-level logic. Then you simply add components to compose a working object. Component-based architecture is not necessarily GUI specific, but it seems like a close match to the code snippets you are providing.

The good news is that there's a lot written about component-based architectures, so you'll be able to leverage that to evaluate possible strengths and weaknesses. Good luck!